# scroll down instead of scroll left

Tags: javascript, jquery, orientation, device

I am trying to scroll the body of a page i'm building up and down as the device tilts up and down.

This plugin scrolls left and right as a device tilts.

How can I make it scroll up and down with the up and down tilt?

```
(function($) {
$.fn.tilt = function(params) {
    items = this;

    params = $.extend( {sensitivity: 1}, params);

    ax = ay = 0;

    window.addEventListener('devicemotion', function (e) {
        ax = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.x * params.sensitivity;
        ay = -e.accelerationIncludingGravity.y * params.sensitivity;

        if(ax > 0) {
            ax -= params.sensitivity;
            if(ax < 0) ax = 0;
        } else if(ax < 0) {
            ax += params.sensitivity;
            if(ax > 0) ax = 0;
        }

    }, false);

    mainLoop = setInterval("moveMe()");

    moveMe = function() {
        $(items).each(function() {
            scrollPos = $(this).scrollLeft() + ax;
            $(this).scrollLeft(scrollPos);
        });
    }
}
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the same thing but with the y parameter?

```
(function($) {
$.fn.tilt = function(params) {
    items = this;

    params = $.extend( {sensitivity: 1}, params);

    ax = ay = 0;

    window.addEventListener('devicemotion', function (e) {
        ax = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.x * params.sensitivity;
        ay = -e.accelerationIncludingGravity.y * params.sensitivity;

        if(ay > 0) {
            ay -= params.sensitivity;
            if(ay < 0) ay = 0;
        } else if(ay < 0) {
            ay += params.sensitivity;
            if(ay > 0) ay = 0;
        }

    }, false);

    mainLoop = setInterval("moveMe()");

    moveMe = function() {
        $(items).each(function() {
            scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop() + ay;
            $(this).scrollTop(scrollPos);
        });
    }
}
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you could use scrollTop() that way! Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. I've implemented it in this page: http://goo.gl/8dZsUQ

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, why not use [$.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/#scrollTop2) to modify the element's vertical scroll value?

```
var tilt_interval_id = setInterval(function(items) { onDeviceTilt(items); }, 50);    

function onDeviceTilt(items) {
   $(items).each(function() {
      var newScrollX = $(this).scrollLeft() + ax;
      var newScrollY = $(this).scrollTop() + ay;
      //Update the horizontal and vertical scroll positions
      $(this).scrollLeft(newScrollX);
      $(this).scrollTop(newScrollY);
   });
}

//Later, if you wish to clear the interval ...
clearInterval(tilt_interval_id);
```

Comment: Like I said ... "If you wish to". I simply meant to show how you could start and stop the behavior if you so chose. You don't actually need that line to get your code working.

Comment: I'm trying to use scrollTop, but it is not working in this page: http://goo.gl/8dZsUQ Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Could you paste the relevant code you are using on the page? Or point me to a specific line number?

Comment: Script is added on line 498. [Here is a link to that script alone].(https://googledrive.com/host/0BwJVaMrY8QdcdTJEVzFWWnpwMEU/tilt.min.js) and initialised on line 1003. Thank you very much!

Comment: These kinds of events are hard for me to replicate. I would suggest adding a very simple 'devicemotion' listener which performs some noticeable change to your page (for example, changing the background color, or even just printing an event message to console). See if you can get something simpler working. If you are testing this on an iOS device, you can also plug your device into your computer and use Safari to check the console output on the device.